# Django search page

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a website that lets visitors search for books using another search engine. I have a script that takes a query, and returns some HTML with the results of the search, but I'm struggling to make a front end for this. I am using django because it seemed like the best option when I started, but now I am going in circles and I can't figure out how to make this thing - I'm just getting overwhelmed because the different tutorials and documentation that I'm reading all go into the advanced stuff before I can get the basic thing working.

Do I need separate search and results templates? Right now I'm getting the error `The view book_search.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`
How can I fix this error and/or design this whole thing better?

Here's what I have so far (the script that returns the results in html is pull.py):
The views and urls are from inside the book_search app.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import pull
from .forms import SearchForm

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to the index page")

def test_search(request):
    context = {'query': 'test query'}
    return render(request, 'book_search/search.html', context)
def search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = pull.main(query)
            context = {'query': query, 'form': form, 'results': results}
    return render(request, 'book_search/results.html', context)
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BookSearchConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'book_search'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.index, name='index'),
    path('test', views.test_search, name='test_search'),
    path('', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

forms.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=200)
```

template base.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="/search/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

template results.html:

```
{% block content %}
    {% results %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It feels like `search` return None when form is not valid, but because of formatting it's hidden from the first sight. Can you re-check if `return render(request, 'book_search/results.html', context)` is actually on the same lever as first `if`?

Comment: Ah, I think that might have been causing the error. Now the error it gives is "local variable 'context' referenced before assignment". The debug page says that the form is invalid, so that makes sense. Any idea why it might be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Since we guessed that form isn't valid (because no POST handler - you do not send anything to the form) and wrong indentation gives `None` response, now you can fix `reference before assignment`:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = SearchForm()
        context = {'form': form}
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = pull.main(query)
            context = {'query': query, 'form': form, 'results': results}
    return render(request, 'book_search/results.html', context)
```

and render errors in results.html template by putting this:

```
 {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does submitting a form always require a POST? Since I am trying to make a search form, I would like to have the query in the URL if possible.

Comment: Well, you can make some way around to use GET by overriding both form validation logic and view, but it's not the go way to go. Try better considering of using AJAX instead.